# How to set value taken from a database as default value for Angular Material Autocomplete

Tags: angular, mat-autocomplete

I would like to get a value from a database and set it as a default value in an autocomplete input box.

**populate clientTypes**

```
clientTypes: any[] = [];
getClientTypes() {
    this.clientService.getClientTypes()
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.clientTypes = [...data];
    });
}
```

**for Autocomplete DisplayWith**

```
displayFn(object): string {
    console.log(object.ClientTypeId);
    return object.Name;
}
```

**in the html**

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Client Type</mat-label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Select Client Type" aria-label="Number" matInput formControlName="clienttype"  [formControl]="clientTypeControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto3">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto3="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn" (optionSelected)='setClientTypeId($event.option.value)'>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let clientType of clientTypes" [value]="clientType">
            {{ clientType.Name }}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
</mat-form-field>
<br>
```

When I use the edit, I get the saved accountTypeId from the database. My problem lies on how to place the fetched accounTypeId into the the matautocomplete as a default option selected but still get the rest of the options?

Thank you.

Comment: also see this for an example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56208062/how-to-set-default-values-for-mat-autocomplete

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in one of two ways:

1. Create a property in the ts file and assign a default value to this on `ngOnInit` and use model binding `[(ngModel)]="your property"` in the input control to set the default value.
2. Use `patchValues` and assign a value to your form control on `ngOnInit`.